# Can the MVVM Light toolkit be used with Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: mvvm-light, xamarin.mac

I've searched for information on this combination but cannot find anything. There are a few discussions of using MVVMCross with Monomac/Xamarin.Mac, but nothing I can find regarding MVVM Light.

Answer (score 0):

it can be used. Just add it via Packages/Nuget to your project and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nuget in question, you might have to swap to the XM 4.5 target framework to get a working build.

More details can be found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/advanced_topics/target-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Use the .NET Standard 1.0 compliant build, `MvvmLightLibsStd10`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibsStd10

Comment: There is no Xamarin.Mac platform support in that package